# Can't find PInvoke DLL 'cellcore' - problem

Tags: c#, windows-ce, motorola

i try the motorola sdk for radio

and i got this error: Can't find PInvoke DLL 'cellcore'.

what can be the problem ?

i'am using MC3190

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the extension to the DllImport:

```
[DllImport("cellcore.dll")]
```

Also see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa446543.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything in the [device's specification sheet](http://www.motorola.com/business/v/index.jsp?vgnextoid=0cfe3acf35e95110VgnVCM1000008406b00aRCRD) that says it has a CDMA/GPRS/GSM modem.  If it has no cell modem, then cellcore certainly isn't going to be on the device.  If it does have a radio, cellcore is probably only going to be there if it's a WinMo version of the OS.